# have some trouble with DWG import in Maya and saving it for Unity3D

Tags: import, export, unity-game-engine, maya, dwg

I have a problem with exporting a 3D Model from Maya, imported from a AutoCAD (DWG File) as a 3D Object.  (for using it in Unity3D at the end)

I have downloaded this dwg file from AutoCad. [DWG File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15710714/conference_room.dwg)

The I have open it in Maya 2014 and save it as a Maya ASCII file.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15710714/conference_room.ma

No when I trying to import the MA file into Unity3D it does not work. (The file seems to be empty :( )

I guess the problem is Maya, maybe I have to setup or transform the imported DWG Data in Polygons or something else.

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is full of NURBS geometry but Unity only recognizes polygon geometry.  Select the objects in Maya and use **Modify > Convert > Nurbs to Polygons**  to convert them